# Full USB install not booting?

Tags: system-installation

Okay I'm puzzled and been trying to solve this for days.
I'm almost giving up on having Ubuntu.

I've used Zorin will no problems, full install on USB. Boots up fine no issues.
But I'm trying to install Ubuntu on the same USB stick. Exact same options under the installer.
Mount point, bootloader location etc.

However it will not boot with Ubuntu full install.
I've tried disabling UEFI boot in BIOS, changed boot priorities and so on.
I know the stick boots as Zorin has no issues. I didn't even disable UEFI boot in BIOS and Zorin boots up fine.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what version of ubuntu you are attempting to install as well as what version of zorin did work.  This could be a kernel issue so what kernel version was working with zorin (`uname -a`)?

Comment: For reviewers to consider if finding this post in the close queue: The OP solved this and [posted an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/366305). The answer is specific enough I believe it would likely be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

Its Ubuntu 13.10 and Zorin 7.1 Core.

I figured it out, I had to disable UEFI boot before installing. It obviously checks what is enabled and writes some bootloader based on that.

So disabling UEFI prior to installation it wrote GRUB2 bootloader.